# Inbox and achievements dialogs won't load on sites other than MSE (error 500)

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

The achievements dialog is failing to load on several sites for me. It works fine on Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow, but on any other site I've tried (main or meta, including main Stack Overflow) the dialog fails to load and eventually errors out with an error 500 after 21 seconds.

**Left: here, right: other sites.**

[image] [image]

**The same is occurring with my inbox.**

It's working exactly the same way on this PC as it is on my phone, and this occurs even if I disable Privacy Badger and my userscripts.

My network tab in my developer console consistently reports the inbox request failing after 21 seconds with an error 500, and an "Oops! Something Bad Happened" page for the response:

[image]
[image]

Sites where the inbox & achievements dialogs load:

- Here on Meta Stack Exchange
- Meta Stack Overflow

Sites where I've seen they won't:

- Stack Overflow (main only)
- RPG Stack Exchange (main or meta)
- Board & Card Games Stack Exchange (main or meta)
- Arqade (main or meta)
- Game Dev Stack Exchange (main or meta)

Comment: Inbox reported on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366531/internal-server-error-when-opening-my-inbox

Comment: Inbox is sometimes slow, but it is loading for me

Comment: Looks like SE got some DNS issues now.

Comment: @rene Thanks, I re-checked my console's network tab and I'm getting the same result, a 500 error.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've managed to confirm I'm actually getting a 500 error, so it might be something other than that.

Comment: This seems to be working again for me now.