# Achievements dialog doesn't load – sometimes

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog, 500-server-error

Since 6-8 days, or maybe even longer, I notice that the achievement dialog doesn't always load correctly. It doesn't matter on which Stack Exchange site I am, or which browser I use; I keep seeing a spinner for 5 seconds and then it just disappears. At the same time, opening the achievements dialog in the Stack Exchange app works fine; there are also moments when it works on the main site too.

[image]

This morning, I could reproduce it with the Firefox developer tab open; the XHR call to `achievements` seems to be running into an error:

[image]

There are no details mentioned on the error page, the HTML of it is [here](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/c386b89c86640854676a949d6755035c). Other dialogs in the top bar (in particular the Notification Inbox, which was mentioned to be buggy as well in the [suggested duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309412)) work fine.

Comment: Same happens to me.  FireFox/Win7.

Comment: It's been like this for years... pretty sure also reported before. (Though sometimes those crashes are more often)

Comment: Maybe it didn't load 5% of the times before; now it's more like 5% of the times when it *does* work. And the problem on MSE is just as bad as everywhere else.

Comment: Same bug in disguise: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180605/an-error-occured-while-loading-whats-that. :)

Comment: Also, doppelgreener posted a comment stating that it doesn't happen anymore, but it does.

Comment: It happens sometimes, that's the key. For me it's about once a week... random times.. totally no way to reproduce. Something somewhere is off, most likely query timing out, dev should look into it, find that query, and fix it by making it less "heavy".

Comment: @ShadowWizard It happens for me more than 50% of the time.

Comment: I've only really noticed it in the past week or so.  Prior to that, it was pretty snappy most of the time.

Comment: This last few days I have 100% failure to load the cheevos dropdown

Comment: OK, close vote retracted.

Comment: I've noticed this a *lot* in the last few days, in both Firefox (Windows) and Chrome (Mac).  I'd wondered if a userscript were somehow to blame but I haven't been able to isolate it to one if so.  (That the problem is somewhat ND doesn't help with debugging.)  Thanks for catching the error; I hope they can fix this.  It's super-annoying!  If I want to see achievements my best bet is to go to a chat page instead; it seems to work there fine with the old topbar.

Comment: @Monica unlike many other bugs, this one isn't related to browser or userscripts... it's purely server side issue.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, I was talking about the thought process I went through when trying to figure out the problem *before* seeing this post.  Now we have an error, which tells us it's not something we're doing.  With the prevalence of userscripts to smooth use of SE, that wasn't a given.

Comment: I, also, have been experiencing this issue over the last few/several days (couple weeks?). What's worked for me is to just open it in a different tab within the same browser (FF, primarily). I haven't looked in the console to see if there are any errors. I'll try to remember to do so next time.

Comment: You still encountering this?

Comment: @Shog9 not anymore yesterday evening and this morning. What have you done? :P

Comment: Not sure what was going on here, @Glorfindel; my suspicion is it was connected to some of the other issues we've been seeing with rep history queries. Lemme know if it reappears.

Comment: @Shog9 I hate to bring bad news on Friday afternoon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX5U5.png